# Output Keyboard/Mouse Presses?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, mouseevent, keyevent

In my program, I want to replicate the user pressing a key on the keyboard and mouse clicks.

Think about it like an auto-typer where the program types something in a word document over and over at various delays.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you try by now? Please show your code, that does not work, or concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

For simulating key presses you can use the `QKeyEvent` class which describes a key event and post that using `QCoreApplication::postEvent`.

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter);
qApp->postEvent (receiver, event)
```

You can set the global position of the mouse by

```
QCursor::setPos(100,100);
```

Simulating the mouse events are like:

```
QMouseEvent * event = new QMouseEvent ((QEvent::MouseButtonPress), QPoint(500,500),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::NoModifier   );

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)this,(QEvent *)event);
```

Comment: How can I make the receiver just global?

Comment: Nevermind, I decided to go with keybd_event from the MSDN documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest QTest namespace key and mouse simulation functions, e.g.

```
QTest::keyClick()
QTest::mouseClick()
```

You'll find documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270446/1526758) in the next topic. Answer has a link to OS depended implementation of Keyboard / Mouse event generation. It can be helpful for you.